# Debug ruby / rails with gedit?

Tags: ruby, gedit

Is there a plugin to debug ruby and/or rails from within gedit?  Similar to how ruby-debug-ide works with Rubymine?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](http://gentoopebble.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/ruby-rails-tools/) the Terminal plugin for gEdit can assist with debugging:

> And finally, the indispensable Terminal. This tool sits at the bottom
>   of your gEdit window, completing your Ruby on Rails work environment.
>   The terminal is great for running Ruby scripts, generating app
>   components, debugging, and starting the application server–all without
>   moving away from the file tree on your left and any open text files.
>
> You will find all of the plugins I mentioned in gEdit by default, or
>   with the addition of the “gedit-plugins” package from the
>   repositories.

Comment: Thanks, but that just uses ruby-debug in a terminal window, I am looking for something that integrates with the IDE

Comment: @AndrewMarshall - Indeed it is, but so is vim, but vim has https://github.com/astashov/vim-ruby-debugger which is what I want for gedit.    Also here's a PHP debug extension for gedit http://code.google.com/p/gedbp/